# Using WebDav for a Public File Share

Tags: .htaccess, webdav

The question in brief: How can I set up WebDav so that unauthenticated users can download files with a URL, but can't access a list or make changes to the share?

The long version:

I'm new to WebDav.  I'd like to replicate the Dropbox/public folder functionality.  That allows any user with the correct URL to download a file, but no unauthenticated user can access a list of the files in the subdirectory or make any changes to the public folder.

I'd like to be able to send my client a URL to a file for download without exposing the whole contents of the share and, importantly, without requiring the client to have a user id and password.

The WebDav directory should also not be alterable or viewable by anyone who doesn't have a user id and password.

The WebDav directory is isolated on my server and I can alter .htaccess files.

Comment: There's no question in this post, just a wishlist.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear.  I'll try again: How can I set up WebDav so that unauthenticated users can download files with a URL, but can't access a list or make changes to the share?

Comment: In that case, it's not really a programming question. I think it might be worth reading the FAQ to learn more about what type of questions should be asked here.

Comment: While my question admittedly doesn't involve a programming language, when I search for "WebDav Configuration", I get 364 hits.  I've looked at the help center and I don't see anything which would disqualify my inquiry.  It's a reasonable technical question that doesn't duplicate another question and is susceptible of a straightforward response.  Please take my question off hold.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is very clearly outside the scope of stack overflow. If you find other examples that are also outside the scope of SO, then that does not make it less so. You should try the serverfault website, but even there it's better to at least have *something* to show before asking others to do your work for you.

Comment: I don't know why you're taking this position.  Perhaps you're having a bad day?  At any rate, you've successfully blocked me from asking a legitimate question that is completely within the bounds of Stack Overflow.  If you feel that is a success, then congratulations.

Comment: I know it can be frustrating, because I've been in the same position as you have. Generally though if you're able to provide some code that has a problem that can be solved, it's a good stack overflow question. If you're asking someone to configure your server, it's on the serverfault sister site: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: But as I said, even there it would be tremendously helpful to share what you've tried, and why that's not working. It increases the chances of getting a satisfying answer by a long shot.

Comment: If you do not want to show clients a directory listing or allow them to alter anything in the share, then why are you attempting to use WebDAV at all? WebDAV is, put simply, extensions to HTTP to support more sophisticated actions than are provided in the HTTP specs. If you just want to give someone a URL to a file, then just put the file on your server within the web root and send the URL to the client.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw I didn't see you comment before - my apologies. I have to confess that you're absolutely right. I fixated on accomplishing a task using WebDav -- mostly because I have a nice WebDav client which would make administration easy -- when it wasn't the right tool for the job.  I ended up adopting exactly your suggestion of using a web server with tightened Apache configuration directives to only allow URLs that point to existing files -- not folders -- and that force https. It's been working well for this task.  Thank you!